# DataGridView - ComboBoxColumn Not Working

Tags: vb.net

I am dynamically adding a column to a `datagridview` after I populate it using a `DataView.`

However my code is adding the `ComboBoxColumn` but I cannot seem to either click the ComboBox and have the values show or get any behavior out of the Combobox.

I've searched around but cannot seem to find any reason as to why, can someone please take a look at my code and let me know.

```
If dgv.Columns.Contains("ResultCol") = False
            'Add The ComboBox Column 
            Dim cmbcol as New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn                                
            with cmbcol                    
                .HeaderText = "Result"
                .Name = "ResultCol"
                '.Items.Add({"Test1","Test2","Test3"})
                .Items.Add("Test1")
                .Items.Add("Test2")
                .FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
                .DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
                .DisplayIndex = DGV.Columns.Count - 1                    
            End With
            dgv.Columns.Add(cmbcol)
End If
```

Comment: You should [read this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476).

Comment: The syntax of your code is incorrect

Comment: And did you copy this code from somewhere?  because your if statement block does not contain "Then"

Comment: @preciousbetine Well yes I copied it from my VStudio IDE, it isn't necessary to use a 'Then'

Comment: @jmcilhinney That explains how to do it using the IDE, doesn't help with dynamically adding it.

Comment: who told you it isn't necessary to use Then. without the then included in your if block ; your code will not even get compiled

Comment: @preciousbetine - Its compiling a running fine my friend.

Comment: Then try setting the Displayindex to 0.

Comment: Why do you want to add the column in code rather than in the designer to begin with?

Comment: @jmcilhinney because it is added dynamically only if values exist for it to be added.

Comment: @preciousbetine - Display Index only organises where in the DGV this column appears. This is set to count - 1 to place it always at the end.

Comment: You know that a `DataGridViewColumn` has a `Visible` property, so you can hide a column added in the designer. That said, anything you do in the designer just generates code anyway, so if you add the column you want in the designer then you can see exactly what code you need to create it at run time.

Comment: @jmcilhinney - irrespective the column doesn't behave correctly whether I've added it dynamically or not. Added it dynamically shouldn't have any bearing on the behavior - the behavior is my query it is not 'Dropping Down' as it should do for a ComboBox.

Comment: What are you expecting this column to do exactly? Combo box columns are generally used to select values from related tables, That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Re: "Well yes I copied it from my VStudio IDE, it isn't necessary to use a 'Then' " My copy of VS 2017 will not allow me to leave the line or save the file without adding the `Then` for me.

Comment: @Mary - I did a nice GIF showing both the empty Error List and also the program compiling, running and the stepping through the code. https://imgur.com/a/d0HknaC

Comment: Amazing! I can't press Start or F5 or leave the line, or save without `Then` being added. Must be a different setting somewhere. Apparently the IDE cares but not the compiler.